# How to solve TypeError: Failed to fetch in Qt for WebAssembly?

Tags: c++, qt, webassembly

I am trying to run my Qt program in the browser using WebAssembly. I followed the guide and was able to get .html, .js and .wasm files in the end. However, when I try to run the index.html file by "double clicking" it, I get the above mentioned error. When I run using emrun --browser=chrome index.html, it works fine. How can I solve this issue?

Edit:
I looked under the console errors and got this: Fetch API cannot load file:///home/siya/QtProjects/test/NotepadApplication.js. URL scheme "file" is not supported.

Edit 2: Here is a snippet of qtloader.js:249:

```
247     function fetchResource(filePath) {
248         var fullPath = config.path + filePath;
249         return fetch(fullPath).then(function(response) {
250             if (!response.ok) {
251                 self.error = response.status + " " + response.statusText + " " + response.url;
252                 setStatus("Error");
253                 return Promise.reject(self.error)
254             } else {
255                 return response;
256             }
257         });
258     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this behavior is expected: browsers such as Google Chrome disable reading from files, for security reasons. Uploading this to an online server will work.

Comment: Installing [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) and just running `serve <somedir>` is a convenient way of mitigating this issue. You can serve from localhost just fine, it's just that there is a fundamental difference between serving from a server on localhost and opening a file.

Comment: Yes, in the initial post I did mention that it is possible and does work using the "emrun" command, but doesn't work when simply double clicking the html file. Thank you.